# How to get the input value from a template literal and assign it to a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have tried to get the class or id attribute of the input field from this template literal and after that, I will like to assign it to a variable so that I can use the add Event Listener method to asset the value of the user's input when they enter letter in the input filed. But I am confused about how to implement this. I will be pleased if someone help can help me out.

```js
// search bar function
const searchBar = () => {
  const createSearchForm = `
    <form action="#" method="get">
      <input type="search" id="search-input" class="search-input" placeholder="Search...">
      <input type="submit" value="&#x1F50D;" id="search-submit" class="search-submit">
    </form>`;
  searchParent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', createSearchForm)
}
searchBar();
```

Comment: On the input type submit you need to add an event such as 'onclick' or . 'onsubmit' and at that time you can fetch the value of the search field.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DOMParser()`:

```js
const createSearchForm = `
  <form action="#" method="get">
      <input type="search" id="search-input" class="search-input" placeholder="Search...">
      <input type="submit" value="&#x1F50D;" id="search-submit" class="search-submit">
  </form>`;
var val = new DOMParser().parseFromString(createSearchForm,"text/html").querySelector("input[type='submit']").value;
console.log(val);
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Ritesh Khandekar. Thanks very much for reaching out, but I am not getting the user's input value. I am sorry for the first post It was a mistake from me.  The real post is  mentioned above

Comment: Can you please explain what do you want step wise?

Comment: If you want to get ID of input then just change code in the snippet to :`new DOMParser().parseFromString(createSearchForm,"text/html").querySelector("input[type='submit']").getAttribute("id")`